# Matching a valid version number inside case statement

Tags: bash, regular-expression, pattern-matching, case

I want to match a version number inside a `case` statement. The version number could look like this

```
1.12.0.32
1.12.0.32.1
2.10.0.30.1.2
```

and is stored inside a shell variable: `version`.

As I searched on the internet, it's little tricky to match a regex inside a `case`-statement. But, does anyone has an idea or could help on how it can be done inside the `case`-statement?

I tried the following, but it didn't work:

```bash
case "$version" in
    "([0-9]+\.*)+")
                  echo "Correct"
        ;;
                 *)
                  echo "Not Correct"
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: What exactly would be correct or incorrect?

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity: well, that's just i've used `echo` for testing purpose, if it matches the `version_num` then it should print `Correct`, or else print `Not Correct`...thanks

Comment: Yes but what would be the comparison, could you give an example? If you want to match the exact string why not just use that in your case statement?

Comment: Or what makes a version number valid or not?

Comment: In other words, are those three examples correct and anything else incorrect? Or is it the shape rather then the digits that are to be checked?

Comment: What characters are allowed in a version number?  Is `5.10.2-rc1+debian2.0` a valid version number or not?

Comment: @TobySpeight: The version number would include only the digits with decimals as per the examples posted in the question.

Comment: What about `1` - is that a valid version?  It would be better to give a proper definition; specification by example leaves too many unknowns, especially when there are no negative examples (i.e. no list of strings that shouldn't match).

Answer (score 7):

`case` only supports shell patterns, and not regexes. But Bash supports regexes out of the box with a different syntax.

If you mean "any number of decimal numbers separated by dots", and e.g. no trailing letters or tags, then the pattern `^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*$` would perhaps be appropriate. `([0-9]+\.*)+` would also match strings with consecutive or trailing dots, like `1.2..3.`. So:

```
#!/bin/bash
re='^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*$';
if [[ $version =~ $re ]]; then
    echo "'$version' matches the pattern"
else
    echo "'$version' doesn't match"
fi
```

The regex says to look for
any number of decimal digits (`[0-9]+`), followed by any number of groups (`(·)*`) consisting of a literal dot (`\.`) and any number of decimal digits (`[0-9]+`). `^` and `$` lock the pattern to the start and end of the string, otherwise a matching substring would be enough for a match.

That would allow a version string without any dots, like `123`. If you want to require at least two numbers and the dot, then use `^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)+$` (changing the last `*` to a `+`).

<sub>Note that depending on the locale, what `[0-9]` matches might be a bit surprising, it could include some weirder Unicode digits. Spelling out the allowed characters with `[0123456789]` would be stricter in that, but is more awkward and error-prone to write.</sub>

Answer (score 6):

`case` matches against shell patterns, not regular expressions. So instead of a regex like `^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*$` you can use:

```
case $version in
  '' | *[!0123456789.]* | .* | *. | *..* ) echo invalid;;
  * ) echo fine;;
esac
```

i.e. "invert" the matching sense, using standard shell patterns to detect invalid cases.

Note that the `extglob` bash option applies to matching in `case` statements. So if you have that set with `shopt -s extglob`, then those extended patterns like `+()`, `*()`, etc. gain their special meanings, and you could do a more regex-like positive match by using `+([0123456789])*(.+([0123456789]))` (shell patterns are already "anchored" to the beginning and end).

Comment: one could also use ksh-style extended globs if the `extglob` shell option is set I think? so something close to the OPs regex might be `+([0-9])*(.+([0-9]))`

Comment: Ah, inverting the test is indeed a nice standard solution here. But those look like standard shell patterns, so no need for `extglob` there. Using steeldrivers's `+([0-9])*(.+([0-9]))` would need `extglob` though.

Answer (score 4):

If it doesn't have to be `case` and you allow the use of an external tool like `grep`, you can use an `if` statement which might provide more flexibility:

```bash
if grep -q -E '^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*$' <<< "$version"
then
    printf "%s is a valid version\n" "$version"
else
    printf "%s is NOT a valid version\n" "$version"
fi
```

This will accept version strings that consist of

- at least one field of one or more consecutive digits (`[0-9]+`), followed by
- zero or more fields that start with a separating `.` (*escaped as `\.` since a simple `.` in RegExes means "any character"*), followed by one or more consecutive digits (again `[0-9]+`).

The exhaustive nature of the match is ensured by anchoring it to the start (`^`) and end (`$`) of the string, so that a mere sub-string match would not trigger the result.